# An advice about a suitable Database design and implementation with C#

Tags: c#, sql, webforms

Stores Table : a table to store information about different stores

```
StoreId     Name       PlaceCode  
--------    --------   --------     
1           Addidas     AB1         
2           Nike        KS3         
3           Puma        LS6         
4           Nike        AS2         
5           Nike        WR4
```

Areas Table

```
AreaId   Area
------   -------
1        DownTown
2        UpTwon
```

StoresArea Table :
**Edit**

```
StoreId   AreaId
-------   -------
1         1
2         2
3         2
4         1
5         2
```

Nike for example has more than a branch for it's store
so my idea was to have more than a record with name attribute "nike" but the other attributes will contain the information about the branch.

I used the StoresArea Table to create a many-to-many relationship but I think it can be achieved with a one-to-many relation...and it's confusing, so I was hoping for a good advice so it could help me follow a good practice!

I created a class named store, to hold the information about each store..but i want to add an additional variable and I think it will be an array, this variable will hold information about all the branches of a given store.

I think this information will be:
1 - the branch's PlaceCode
2 - Id so I could provide a url using querystring to access all the other branches ?StoreId=Id
3 - the branch's area
to go straight to the point, i want the detailed page of any given store to have a field called branches, which will display the Branch's Area + the PlaceCode of all the other available branches. E.g "Branches : Downtown: AS2" and the Downtown word will be clickable to link to the branch!

I know It's not clear enough! but I hope you'll get it
sure, you can ask about any further details or questions make the picture more clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kashef,

Every store is only in a single region, correct? If so, create a store table with a foreign key relationship to the region table (i.e., RegionID in the store table).

If different stores are part of the same brand/company, create a company table and set up a foriegn key to the store table.

The setup would look like

Region Table ---> Stores <---- Company

Is that the situation you have? If so, let me know and I'll talk about the classes.

Erick

**Edited based on comments**

In that case, what you really need a many-to-many relationship between Regions and Stores, with a distinct primary key (i.e., not RegionID + StoreID).

Region Table ---> RegionTable <--- Stores <---- Company

This will allow you to have multiple stores in a single region. However, it also allows multiple regions for a single store! You might be able to work around this with a constraint that ensures that each store only has a single region.

Does this make sense?

Erick

Comment: Actually a region or an area could have more than one store for the same brand, with a different address

Nike could have two branches in DownTown! so what will make them unique is to display the address or the place code with them like in "Branches : DownTown, AS2 - DownTown, SD1"

Comment: that actually makes sense, and the idea started to come up already...but I can't still imagine how I'll display for example, all the branches for a specific store (P.S : the StoreCode plays the part of the store's address, so this is what makes every store unique) see I edited the third table to have 2 Nike stores in the same area to demonstrate the many-to-many relationship here.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, I recommend using the business language to define your software concepts. So, I would use the word "branch" to define the concrete, physical place where people can buy stuff. I would make defining this shared business language pretty much the first step in the project.

It also helps to then use this business language in a semi-formal syntax to work through the concepts. I think that you say the following.

- There are many companies (Nike, Adidas etc.)
- Each company has one or more branches.
- A branch has one, and only one area code.
- One area code may have 0 or more branches.

In that case the model is the first solution Erick T suggests (forgive me for not using the same names he does).

Specifically:

Table COMPANY

```
COMPANY_ID     NAME
---------------------
1              Nike
2              Adidas
3              Reebok
```

Table AREA

```
AreaId   Area
------   -------
1        DownTown
2        UpTown
```

Table BRANCH

```
BRANCH_ID       COMPANY_ID       AREA_ID       ADDRESS
-------------------------------------------------------
1               1                1             The Mall
2               1                2             High Street
3               2                1             Near MacDonalds
4               3                2             Out of town
```

To find other stores for the company for a given branch, you only need the branch ID:

```
select *
from branch
where company_id =
 (select company_id from branch where branch_id = %current_branch_id%
```